Worm fanfic where Taylor and Panacea team up
I'm rereading Metastable, which has a plotline of Panacea realizing Taylor has powers accidentally when touching her, and eventually using her powers to fight alongside her. Later, there's a plan to mess with the E88 by changing people's skin colors via biomanipulation. It made me suddenly remember another story I read in the last year, probably on Spacebattles, where something like that happened, but Taylor had her canon powers and Amy is a much less reluctant combatant.
I remember that Taylor encourages Amy, early on, to experiment with her power, developing techniques involving shooting sugar water with engineered microbes, first just bioluminescent but later having further effects. At one point, they realize they've crossed a line when Amy changes a bunch of E88 gang members to have black skin and it's treated like biological terrorism. Prior to that, they've just been incredibly effective by doing things like having Taylor's bugs inject villains with something like ketamine to knock them out before they realize it's a fight.
Panacea's cape alter ego is mistaken as male, which gives her a chance to openly flirt with Victoria, which eventually leads to a scene where both Amy and her cape alter ego (code name Biohazard?) attend an awards ceremony at Fosberg Gallery, courtesy of Amy engineering a humanoid insect body that Taylor can control with her power. That eventually leads to some really weird scenes where Taylor (in Boston after they move out of Brockton Bay, where things have gotten too heated?) puppets a maid body that looks a lot like Victoria who seduces Amy, while Taylor acts like the maid is entirely independent of her.
One quirk, departing from canon a bit, is that Taylor seems to be becoming less mentally human as she indulges her power, using Amy as a morality chain to keep her from just killing her enemies in their sleep to end problems. This may have been feeding into the whole "treat a puppeted body as not her" things since she's mentally compartmentalized that personality as someone else.

OK. I think I found it, although not until writing most of the question. Heredity by Beaconhill looks to be the one. It starts differently than I remember, with Taylor and Amy becoming friends after Taylor joins Arcadia, and then Taylor being there for the Undersider bank robbery, and neutralizing them after Tattletale takes Panacea hostage, and reveals Panacea's link to Marquis. Taylor accidentally outs herself by virtue of Amy knowing that the Undersiders got taken out by bug bites, and the insects acting weird around Taylor. But the rest of looks like it checks out and it is in my browser history.
The name of Biohazard is considered, but vetoed.

"Biohazard."
I turned it over in my head a few times. There was a hero named 'Hazard,' I thought, but... "Still too villainous."
"You named me Skitter. Deal with it. Anyway, Quarantine."
Not friendly. Not friendly at all. But it did have a ring to it... "You know, I could go with that."

Found with a search for worm fanfic amy "biohazard"
I did not remember Amy learning of her heritage being such a major factor in how things change. I had remembered a scene where she and Taylor wind up at her old family home, but the details were so vague in my memory that I couldn't remember how they found it.
